# renedering xml using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a XML dump like this ..

```
<reporter-output>
    <line>
      <![CDATA[PAss 1 ]]>
    </line>
    <line>
      <![CDATA[<td><a href='C:\WorkSpace\GSSR\Resources\ImageNotFound.png.jpg'><img src='C:\Resources\ImageNotFound.png.jpg' height='100' width='100' /></a></td>]]>
    </line>
    <line>
      <![CDATA[PAss 2 ]]>
    </line>
    <line>
      <![CDATA[<a href="C:\WorkSpace\GSSR\Resources\ImageNotFound.png"> Clickhere </a>]]>
    </line>
    <line>
      <![CDATA[<a href=C:\WorkSpace\GSSR\Resources\ImageNotFound.png>click to open screenshot</a>]]>
    </line>
 </reporter-output>
```

I need to create a hyperlink for href ie to 'clickhere'.
I am trying it in xslt but I'm getting a plain text like

```
 '[<a href="C:\WorkSpace\GSSR\Resources\ImageNotFound.png"> Clickhere </a>]]'
```

my xlst..

```
    <!-- Reporter output file -->
    <xsl:result-document href="{testng:absolutePath('reporterOutput.html')}" format="xhtml">
        <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <xsl:call-template name="htmlHead"/>
            <body>
                <h2>Reporter output</h2>
                <xsl:for-each select="reporter-output/line">
                    <div>
                        <code>
                            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                        </code>
                    </div>
                </xsl:for-each>
                <xsl:call-template name="powered-by"/>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:result-document>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Could you please attach `XSLT` file?

Comment: The file is too big,can i send it accross,thanks

Comment: Please edit your question to be actually meaningful - your edits have made any answers irrelevant as we can't see what you actually asked originally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to change

```
                    <code>
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    </code>
```

to output the link element then use

```
                    <code>
                        <xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
                    </code>
```

Note that `disable-output-escaping="yes"` is an optional serialization feature not supported by all XSLT processors respectively in all transformation scenarios.